# validate date against many formats in javascript

Tags: javascript, momentjs

i have couple of date formats that we accept.

```
const dateFormats =['yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.SSSZ','yyyy.MM.DD','MM.DD.yyyy','MM-DD-yyyy','yyyy/MM/DD','MM/DD/yyyy']
```

i want validate incoming date with these formats? how do i do that in javascript?
here is what im trying : -

```
let isValid = dateFormats.some(dateFormat => {
  if(typeof val === 'string' && val.indexOf(' ') < 0)
    return moment(val, dateFormat, true).isValid()
  else return false
})
```

but its not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass multiple date formats to `moment`

```js
const val = new Date()

const dateFormats = ['yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.SSSZ', 'yyyy.MM.DD', 'MM.DD.yyyy', 'MM-DD-yyyy', 'yyyy/MM/DD', 'MM/DD/yyyy']
const valid = moment(val, dateFormats, true).isValid()

console.log({ valid })
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.1/moment.min.js" integrity="sha512-qTXRIMyZIFb8iQcfjXWCO8+M5Tbc38Qi5WzdPOYZHIlZpzBHG3L3by84BBBOiRGiEb7KKtAOAs5qYdUiZiQNNQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
```

Comment: moment is not supported anymore.

Comment: @ulou it's still ok for use, but you're right, it's probably better to use luxon https://moment.github.io/luxon/

Comment: This question can be answered by reading the [documentation](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-formats/) or with one of the many duplicates...

Comment: "2018-04-25T14:05:15.953Z" validation is failing for this.. moment gives false for this when its clearly accepted